# You've heard this all before

Tags: pattern

You turn on your phone in the morning and see you've gotten 9 texts from yout friend Bob. Bob is one of those guys who sends a new text each time he starts a new sentence (and sometimes even in between). Here's what they say :

1. So I met this girl, really unaware of her good looks. (Bob never bothers to say hi)
2. It was the blasted last day of the week,
3. so I decided to go in for the kill.
4. It seems like a whole year passed,
5. and that I had to tread a great distance.
6. Man, I went straight down to hell,
7. and then climbed to paradise.
8. I'm telling you, I'm thinking so much about her, it's physically impossible...
9. Anyway, she's German, so for her birthday, I plan on getting her

You sigh as you put down your phone. His story is really unnecessarily lyrical, and he didn't even finish his last text. However, it seems to you like there is a progression, and that somehow, **you've heard all of this before** somewhere.
 Suddenly, you know what Bob will get the girl for her birthday.

---

*What is the progression behind Bob's texts ? What will he get the girl ?*

---

Hint

> You wonder if Bob got her number.

Comment: I'll bet it's paraphrase of some well known song lyrics (not my field though)

Comment: Does the country matter for this puzzle?

Comment: @mmking Could be. #2 sounds like rot13(Fhaqnl Oybbql Fhaqnl)...

Comment: you are on the right tracks jafe and mmking. 
The country doesn't really matter. Germany is meant to narrow down the possibilities for the birthday gift, but you need to understand the pattern first.

Comment: @jafe that was the first think I thought for #2 as well!

Comment: Also rot13(Fgnvejnl gb Urnira) for #7?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So the pattern appears to be:

> each message references a song, where the list number appears in the song title or band name.

Specifically,

*1. So I met this girl, really unaware of her good looks.*

> What Makes You Beautiful - **One** Direction ("Everyone else in the room can see it / Everyone else but you")

*2. It was the blasted last day of the week,*

> Sunday, Bloody Sunday - U**2**

*3. so I decided to go in for the kill.*

> The Kill - **Thirty** Seconds to Mars (from OP, in the comments)

*4. It seems like a whole year passed,*

> The **Four** Seasons - Vivaldi (from OP, in the comments)
>  <del>**Four** Seasons in One Day - Crowded House (maybe??)</del>

*5. and that I had to tread a great distance.*

> I'm Gonna Be (**5**00 Miles) - The Proclaimers

*6. Man, I went straight down to hell,*

> The Number of the Beast - Iron Maiden (i.e. **6**66) (from OP, in the comments)
>  <del>...possibly Highway to Hell (AC/DC), but no reference to 6, so maybe some other song with **6**66 in the title?</del>

*7. and then climbed to paradise.*

> Stairway to Heaven - Led Zeppelin (as in Stairway to [**S**]<sup><sub>H</sub></sup>**e**<sup><sub>a</sub></sup>**ven**, confirmed by OP in the comments)
>  <del>Also possibly **Seven**th Heaven - Gwen Guthrie?</del>

*8. I'm telling you, I'm thinking so much about her, it's physically impossible...*

> **Eight** Days a Week - The Beatles ("Love you ev'ry day girl, Always on my mind." for the physically impossible 8 days in a week)

Which leaves us with number nine...

*9. Anyway, she's German, so for her birthday, I plan on getting her*

> **9**9 Luftballons - Nena (German song)
>  ...meaning he's going to buy the girl 99 red balloons.

Comment: Yes ! I'll fill in the other clues, since some of them are somewhat more loose :
3. gur xvyy - guvegl frpbaqf gb Znef
4. I was thinking of (r13)Ivinyqv but I guess anything goes
6. Refers to (r13)gur ahzore bs gur ornfg, ol Veba Znvqra
7. is indeed (r13)Yrq Mrc.. sort of a pun with the previous line, (r13) fgnevjnl gb f'urnira